# maxima and converting output of variable to float

Tags: maxima-software

I can get maxima to solve an equation but can't figure out why it won't show it's numerical value without typing the extra command/step of **float(%)**.   Is there away to automatically convert a solved variable to a numerical format.

Example of equation below:

```
kill(all); 
alpha:float(.0014931); 
endfreq:50; dursec:1200;   
solve(alpha=log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec,float(startfreq));
```

what comes back is

```
startfreq=50%e(44793/25000)
```

or

$\left[ {\it startfreq}=50\,e^{{{44793}\over{25000}}} \right] $

I would like it to say **299.988** instead

Comment: Cross posted to Stack Overflow: [maxima and converting output of variable to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812808/maxima-and-converting-output-of-variable-to-float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want numeric value set numer to true :

```
kill(all)$ 
numer:true$
ratprint: false$
alpha:0.0014931$ 
endfreq:50$ 
dursec:1200$ 
s:solve(alpha=log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec,startfreq)$
s[1];
```

then output will be :

```
startfreq=299.988159465253
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Wrap float() around the final expression:

```
kill(all); 
alpha:float(.0014931); 
endfreq:50; dursec:1200;   
float(solve(alpha=log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec,float(startfreq)));
```